# Slider revolution plugin briefly shows all slides on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, revolution-slider

I have a slight problem with slider revolution plugin, where on page load, I can see for half second captions for all slides. They disappear after that and then the first slides loads normally (first the dummy loader and then actual image with captions and animations). Is there a quick fix to get rid of this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a height on the containing div and put 'overflow-y:hidden'.  What this will do is only show the first loaded slide, and the others that load won't be visible.

If you match the height of the containing div to the height of a slide, then it should only show the first slide.

When it scrolls (assuming that the slides are all the same size and the carousel doesn't resize on each slide), it should then show the next slide in the correct height.

Comment: Please explain what your suggestion does and why it will solve the problem. A short answer like this usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.